# How to get a trigger when Facebook Messenger chat head appears?

Tags: android, service, facebook-messenger

Facebook uses a service `MessagingService` in Android to show chat heads on your smartphone, in this service, a `view` is basically added in a `Window` as per [this](http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics) and [this](http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/) article.

Whenever the Facebook Messenger chat-head appears on the screen I want to get a **trigger** through my application service.

The question is that how to get that trigger when that chat-head appears on the screen.

If there are any solutions or any work-around/hack please feel free to share.